# Localstorage in array

Tags: javascript, css, html, local-storage

What I'm trying to do is get the user's email and name input and .push it into the array emailbook, it does push the .values of the email and name into the array but whenever I store it into the localstorage, it replaces the existing array. Help please thank you!!

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",docIsReady);
        var emailbook;
        function docIsReady(){

            emailbook=localStorage.getItem("emailbook");

            if (emailbook==null){
                emailbook=[];
                console.log(emailbook)
            }
            else {  
                emailbook=JSON.parse(emailbook);
                console.log(emailbook)
            }
        }
        function store() {
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var obj = {"name": name, "email": email};
            emailbook.push(obj);
            localStorage.setItem("email", JSON.stringify(emailbook));
        }
        console.log(localStorage);
        //var storedemail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("email"));
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean it replaces the existing array? Is it nulling the other attributes in emailbook?

Comment: The localStorage property is read-only so you can't edit it. only `save`, `read` and `remove` are available for localStorage.

Comment: localstorage stores value by key,you set it with the same key,of course it will replace the old value.

Comment: I assume you meant to use `emailbook` as a key, e.g. `localStorage.setItem("emailbook", JSON.stringify(emailbook));`

Comment: @GeorgeDaniel By replaces existing array I meant by the var emailbook for example emailbook = {"abc@xyz.com"} and the problem is when I type in a new email it replaces {"abc@xyz.com"} into for example {"cba@xyz.com"}

Comment: @LGSon emailbook is just the variable that I wanted to set for the array to start off from somewhere.

Comment: You might missed my point, you use the key `emailbook` to get the item from storage, but you save it using the key `email`, hence any updates won't be found next time....meaning you need to use the same key for both get/set item.

Comment: @LGSon ahh, I see. okay I'll try that. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about reading localStorage in store() method, pushing everything to emailbook array, pushing obj and saving it in localStorage?

Something like this:

```
var name = "foobar";
var email = "mail";
var emailbook = [];
var obj = {"name": name, "email": email};
if(localStorage.getItem('email') != null) {
    var tmp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('email'));
    for(let i = 0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
        emailbook.push(tmp[i]);
    }

}
emailbook.push(obj);
localStorage.setItem("email", JSON.stringify(emailbook));
```

Comment: When I tried it the keys and values just change to [{"name":"foobar","email":"mail"}]. I tried to change var name = document.getElementById("name").value; and likewise for email but it just returns me null

Comment: Try to log (console.log) "document.getElementById("name").value". If it's null, then problem is in your html (maybe wrong id?). Also be sure to not define twice emailbook variable (I defined this variable again in the scope of store function, but you defined it as a global variable)

Comment: I logged document.getElementById("name").value and it came out as it should be but when I logged the variable "name", it came out as null

Comment: <form method="get" enctype="text/plain">
                        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name!">
                        <input id="email" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" required><br>

                        <button onclick="store()"> Yes I'm in! </button>
                    </form>  This is my form that I'm trying to get the value of

Comment: Works well in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2fmzha8y/11/
Can you please post whole solution or create solution where the problem appears? Did you refresh scripts in browser?

Comment: Yes I did refresh the scripts in browser. for my code, I tried to place my <script> tags at the top of the body and at the bottom but both also have the same problems

Comment: okay, right now i managed to get the code to work again but it's still replacing the existing array again. [{"name":"david","email":"abc@gmail.com"}] was the first one i put in. Then when I tried entering a new name and email it replaces to [{"name":"dave","email":"cba@gmail.com"}] rather than adding the new inputs into the array [{"name":"david","email":"abc@gmail.com"},{"name":"dave","email":"cba@gmail.com"}]

Comment: Again, in jsfiddle works:
https://jsfiddle.net/2fmzha8y/15/
If this jsfiddle doesn't help, please code your current store body method. Btw., what was causing the null when you tried to console name variable?

Comment: For some odd reason it just started to work again. Maybe it might be bracket's server problem. I used the exact same code as yours but it didn't work but when I copied and pasted yours from jsfiddle it worked. anyway for the causing the null it just suddenly started working again as well. Now that the problem is solved, thank you so much! I've been pulling out my hair because of this, I'm still a beginner at this as I just started javascript about 3 weeks ago. anyway cheers and thank you again!